# parsing "(" - Not enough )'s

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, compiler-errors

```
killer = killer.Replace("(", "\(");
```

Trying to put a '\' before open brace , it says "Error  1   Unrecognized escape sequence"

I also tried putting a '@' before it , but that results in two back slash.

Comment: " that results in two back slash" - if you're looking at the result in the debugger then realize that the _debugger_ adds a second backslash so you know it's not an escape sequence.  The _actual_ string will only contain one backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double backslash.

```
killer = killer.Replace("(", "\\(");
```

Comment: or `killer = killer.Replace("(", @"\\(");`

Comment: you don't need to use double `\` escape if you prefixed it with `@`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error you are receiving, it looks like you are trying to escape Regex pattern. `Regex` class has built-in function to escape them.

> `Regex.Escape("(")` produces `\(`